# Retrieve Variable Name and Value from az pipeline variable-group

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

I would like to loop through items in a variable-group where the name starts with `add_` and then add these to keyvault.

I have got the variables from a variable-group with:

`az pipelines variable-group variable list` with additional parameters to return name values:

```json
{
  "add_myVaule": {
    "isSecret": null,
    "value": "hello"
  },
  "add_myWorld": {
    "isSecret": null,
    "value": "world"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how I can reference the name (add_myVaule, add_myWorld) and get the value so i can loop through and add the values into a keyvault, something like this:

```
foreach ($var in $vargroup){
   az keyvault secret set --vault-name $(VaultName) --name $var --value $var.value
}
```

Comment: the reference should be $var.key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve variable name and value by the following steps:
1 az pipelines variable-group variable list is a JSON string from your screenshot, you should convert a JSON string to a hash table

```
' your JSON String ' | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
```

And you can see the Hash Table Data structure

[JSON to Hash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuApD.png)

2  run the script and the $($*.key) is to get the Key(add_myVaule,add_myWorld), $($*.value) is to get the corresponding value

```
$variable_group.GetEnumerator() | % { 
    "Current key is: $($_.key)"
        $($_.value).GetEnumerator() | %{
        "Current key is: $($_.key)"
        "Value of $($_.key) is: $($_.value)"
     }
}
```

[print variable name and value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1iDs.png)