# Retrieve Variable Name and Value from az pipeline variable-group?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have got the variables from a variable-group with:

```
$be_common=az pipelines variable-group variable list --group-id <some_id> --output json
```

and the result is something like this:

```
{
  "key1": {
    "isSecret": null,
    "value": "value1"
  },
  "key2": {
    "isSecret": null,
    "value": "value2"
  }
}
```

How can i use the values of the variables in the group later in the pipeline?
For example i want later to execute

```
docker build --build-arg arg1=value1
```

(the value of variable key1 from the group)?
I see here
[Retrieve Variable Name and Value from az pipeline variable-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74111081/retrieve-variable-name-and-value-from-az-pipeline-variable-group)
how they are retrieved, but they are enumerated, and i want to point exactly which variable value i want to use.

Comment: What scripting language? Bash? PowerShell? something else?

Comment: the script for getting the variables is powershell, the place where i want to use them is in docker build command in azure pipeline - - task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build an image for container registry
  inputs:
    command: build arguments: '--build-arg arg1=value1

Comment: Are you using this command `$be_common=az pipelines variable-group variable list --group-id <some_id> --output json` in your pipeline? Is it in a powershell task?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And the result is something similar to what i showed and i would like to use the values of the keys there.

Comment: Add `| convertFrom-json` to parse the output from az-cli and then you can access the data from the powershell object.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! But as i use --output json | ConvertFrom-Json, is there a way to use another flag in order to use the data as poweshell object directly - without transfer through json object?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you update the Q with what you have now, with my trick above and then explain what you want more?